# Javascript Double-Click Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys.. Quick question:

I wrote a simple JS that opens lightBox for image viewing when an image link is clicked. Basically, using jQuery (yes, I was that lazy), I detect the click of an anchor tag, use a regex to make sure that the HREF attribute is to an image file, and if it is, it opens the image in lightBox. It all works fine, except one thing: The anchor needs two clicks before it will open lightBox. Why is that?

Here's the script I wrote:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var href;
    var imageExtensions = /(.)+(.jpg)|(.png)|(.gif)|(.bmp)/;
    //On click of any link
    $("a").live("click",function(event){
        href = $(this).attr("href");
        //If the target URL is an image, use lightbox to open it
            if(imageExtensions.test(href)){
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).attr("class","lightboxIMG");
                //Prevent the link from opening, and open lightbox
                $(".lightboxIMG").lightBox();
                $(this).attr("class","");
            }
    });
//END   
});
```

I don't see what could be causing the user to have to click twice to activate lightBox. If you need a sample to see what I'm referring to, I'm currently using the script in a beta of my new website: http://ctrlshiftcreate.com/photography.php?photo=6&r_folder=

Click "View full size" to see what I mean. I'd greatly appreciate any help - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* what's happening is the `lightbox()` call only sets the anchor up to be a lightbox, it doesn't actually show the lightbox. So, the first click is saying to lightbox "make this a lightbox link", and the second click gets caught by lightbox and actually shows the lightbox.

**edit** Is the live aspect of it important? Or, do you plan on adding more links that you'll need to capture after the document is loaded? If live isn't important, the standard `lightBox()` method should be good enough to catch clicks. If it is, I'd consider writing a `hookAnchors()` style method that you can call after the ajaxing that simply calls `lightBox()` again. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    hookAchors();
});

function hookAnchors() {
    var imageExtensions = /(.)+(.jpg)|(.png)|(.gif)|(.bmp)/;
    $('a')
        .filter(function() {
            return imageExtensions.test($(this).attr("href"))
        })
        .lightBox();
}
```

That way you can call hookAnchors inside your DOM changing code (as a result of `$.get` for example).

Comment: Look at that - worked like a charm! I didn't know that lightbox caught the click on its own.

If I wasn't also a guy, I'd say I love you!

And yeah... I had the whole image gallery running off of AJAX before, but due to bookmarking problems and such, I changed it - that's why I still have the live() function in there.

Thanks so much - that's awesome!